# Error in the file dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am actually following a tutorial to discover Spring framework. I am a beginer with Web technology.

I actually get a problem in my file dispatcher-servlet.xml. I believe that my `<context:component-scan base-package="com.tuto.mehdi" />` is not working cause I have an Error 404 when I launch my project :

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSlrr.png)

[My architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Mg2.png)

**My console error :**

> AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/tutoriel-web-spring/] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'servlet-dispatcher' avr. 06, 2016 2:26:34 PM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
>
> AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/tutoriel-web-spring/bonjour] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'servlet-dispatcher'

---

That's my code. I believe that I did good but I am not able to identify the problem. Hope you could help me!

**WEB.XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <!-- variable de contexte définie dans le WEB-INF-->
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Le listener « ContextLoaderListener » charge la configuration Spring 
    à partir de la variable de contexte « contextConfigLocation ». -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Declaration de la servlet de Spring et de son mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**bonjourController.java (java class not create as servlet)**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
/*
 * indique que le contrôleur traite les requêtes GET dont l'URI est « /bonjour »
 * */
@RequestMapping("/bonjour")
public class BonjourController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String afficherBonjour(final ModelMap pModel) {
        pModel.addAttribute("personne", "Regis");
        return "bonjour";
    }
}
```

**bonjour.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!-- déclration de la "taglib" Spring -->
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><spring:message code="titre.bonjour"/> : ${ personne }</title>
</head>
<body>
    <spring:message code="libelle.bonjour.lemonde" arguments="${personne}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```js
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- Déclaration du bean "messageSource" de classe ReloadableResourceBundleMessagesource  -->
 <!-- permettra de charger les messages internationalisées dans des fichiers messages_xx.properties (voir classpath) -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- active la configuration par annotations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tuto.mehdi" />
    <!-- la déclaration du bean InternalResourceViewResolver indique où chercher la ressource -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/vues/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of dispatcher-servlet.xml?

Comment: For starters stop loading the same configuration twice. You are loading all of your beans twice, once by the `ContextLoaderListener` and next by the `DispatcherServlet`. Either split your configuration or ditch the `ContextLoaderListener`. Also use a more recent version of the `web.xml` with 2.3 (which is from a decade ago or so) you don't have working EL. See http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/ (I suggest at least the 3.0 version).

Comment: Where are you mapping `/tutoriel-web-spring`? If you want to use that, I think you only need to change your `@RequestMapping` to `@RequestMapping("/tutoriel-web-spring/bonjour")`. Or change/add another `servlet-mapping`

Comment: God! sorry I forgot the most important code part!

Thank you M.Denium for your reply.

Didn't understand that is the same thing. Believed I had to have the contextLoaderListener to map with DispatcherServlet.
Then I could delete all from <context-param> (line 8) to </listener> (line 16)?

About the versioning. you'r talking about 3.0, but in my tutorial, the autor already use EL. web.xml 3.0 is not about redirection with @blabla?

Thank you again,

Comment: Christopher, I just want to call my .jsp when my url contain /bonjour. That's not the way to do?

Comment: The `servlet-mapping` says to call the dispatcher if the url contains `/`. It does that, and then tries to find a request mapping with everything after the `/`. Your only mapping is `/bonjour`, but it is trying to find `/tutoriel-web-spring/bonjour`

Comment: I tryed to add this --- <servlet>
     <servlet-name>BonjourController</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.tuto.mehdi.controller.BonjourController</servlet-class>
 </servlet> 
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>BonjourController</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/bonjour</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> --- But still not working. Anyway, the first mapping had to work alone...